# java AES128 And Salesforce Aes128

Tags: crypto

What can I do to make apex's aes128 encryption result and Java's aes128 encryption result the same, please help me,Here are my apex Aes128 encryption methods and Java Aes128 encryption methods:

```
public static String aes128(String content, String password)
{
    //16 byte string. since characters used are ascii, each char is 1 byte.
    Blob key = Blob.valueOf(password);

    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '*** key: ' + key);
    //encrypted blob
    Blob cipherText = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, Blob.valueOf(content));
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '***cipherText : ' + cipherText);
    //encrypted string
    //String encodedCipherText = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cipherText);
    String encodedCipherText = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(cipherText);
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '::::encodedCipherText:' + encodedCipherText);

    return encodedCipherText;
}
```

---

```
public static String encrypt(String content, String password) 
{

    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    secureRandom.setSeed(password.getBytes());
    kgen.init(128, secureRandom);
    SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");
    BASE64Encoder coder = new BASE64Encoder();  
    coder.encode(enCodeFormat);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    byte[] byteContent = content.getBytes("utf-8");
    cipher.init(1, key);
    byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(byteContent);
    String str = Base64.encode(result);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [`Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#!) generates a Blob encrypted with AES in the Cipher Block Chaining mode.

CBC uses an Initialization Vector, which in this method is generated by Salesforce and prepended to the encrypted Blob. Because Salesforce is generating the IV, you cannot expect the ciphertext Blob generated to be identical to that generated by any other application, or indeed another ciphertext Blob generated by Salesforce for the same plaintext at a different time.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't need ciphertext results from different systems to be *identical*, you just need them to be *interoperable* - that is, each system can decrypt the other's output. I'm not a Java programmer myself, but you should be able to decrypt this ciphertext outside Salesforce. Again cf. the Crypto documentation:

> Use either third-party applications or the decryptWithManagedIV method to decrypt blobs encrypted with this method.
>
> These are all industry standard Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) algorithms with different size keys. They use cipher block chaining (CBC) and PKCS5 padding.

If for some reason it's critical that the ciphertext be identical across the two applications (something that smacks to me of bad cryptographic design), you'd certainly need to generate and store the initialization vector yourself and use `encrypt()` on Salesforce.